# Naming or securing a Phone app name

Tags: android, iphone

I have a website aka wingdongding.com not its real name but anyway.I feel I may want to have a phone app for this site created in the semi near future BUT were I to do so would want the phone app to be also called Wingdongding. My question is. How can I kinda register this name for my phone app now before someone else does for app use ? I have already got the .com and .co.uk of the domains but want to secure the app name.

Comment: This is probably not a question for developers. More for a lawyer as you are talking about trademarks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reserve an app name in the Play Store. The app-name is not unique. Just the package-name (application id) (e.g. com.helloworld.app) is unique and cannot be changed.

Comment: Please set it as answer if it helped.